# Volume element of the neighborhood of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, volume

In [this](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.23.1982) paper by da Costa, he derives the geometric potential arising due to the confinement of a quantum particle to a surface. However, I believe this physical context is not relevant to my question:

Let's assume that the metric of the three-dimensional neighborhood of a surface is given by
\begin{equation}
  G_{ab}=\begin{pmatrix}g+q_3(\alpha g+g\alpha^T)+q_3^2\,\alpha g \alpha^T&0\\
0&1\end{pmatrix},
\tag{A}\end{equation}
where $q_3$ is a coordinate normal to the surface, $\alpha$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix of Weingarten coefficients (eqs. $(2),(3)$) and $g=g^T$ is the metric of the surface.

The volume element expressed in curvilinear coordinates is
$$dV=\sqrt{\det G}\,dq_1\,dq_2\,dq_3,\tag{B}$$
which he writes in eq. (8) as
$$dV=f(q_1,q_2,q_3)\sqrt{\det g}\,dq_1\,dq_2\,dq_3,\tag{8}$$
with
$$f(q_1,q_2,q_3)=1+q_3\text{tr}\,\alpha+q_3^2\det\alpha.\tag{9}$$

I'd like to derive $(8)$ and $(9)$. From $(\text{A})$ I get
$$\sqrt{\det G}=\sqrt{\det[g+q_3(\alpha g+g\alpha^T)+q_3^2\,\alpha g\alpha^T]}=\sqrt{\det g}\sqrt{\det[1+q_3(g^{-1}\alpha g+\alpha^T)+q_3^2\,g^{-1}\alpha g\alpha^T]},\tag{C}$$
so the function $f$ should be
$$f(q_1,q_2,q_3)=\sqrt{\det[1+q_3(g^{-1}\alpha g+\alpha^T)+q_3^2\,g^{-1}\alpha g\alpha^T]},\tag{D}$$
but I don't know how to compute this determinant to get $(9)$. Maybe some property of the $\alpha$ matrix is needed, but I'm not familiar with it, so any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit**:
Now I'm seeing in other papers that $(9)$ might be the expansion only up to second order in $q_3$ (higher order terms are not relevant for the analysis of the system).